# How to trigger an okclick event in a Fragment from a button located in a FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying in add Google+ sign in to my app. 
The [example](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) I'm following shows how to set everything up in an Activity, but I'm trying to have everything regarding the sign-in logic in a fragment while having the Sign In button in my main FragmentActivity.
I'm new to Android so I'm not sure how do to this but I wanna know how can I trigger the onClick() event that I have in the fragment (that handles all the sign in stuff) from the Sign In button I have in my FragmentActivity?

I've tried to add this to the onCreate on my Activity:

```
googleAuthButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            googlePlusFragment.onClick(v);
        }
    });
```

This, of course, doesn't work.
I'll appreciate some help with this.

Comment: why dont you just move the "sign-in stuff" in your fragment and have your activity do it since that is where the button it, it make more sense that way. you can always call a method from the fragment to do what you want on the button click

Comment: I have a sign-in option with Facebook as well in the same activity so I wanted to have the sign-in logic for both options on two different fragments and keep the Activity as light as possible. At least, that's my logic here. I'm not sure if this is the best convention.

Comment: like I said you can always create a public method in your fragment and call that on the button click

Comment: I'm confused - you're using a fragment with no UI to handle the log in of a button that's in an activity? If you're just trying to move the code that handles the log in out of the way - like an AsyncTask - just make a separate logIn class. Just seems odd how its currently set up.

Comment: The onClick() method in my Fragment is public. Why doesn't it work when I try to call it from the Activity's onClick?

Comment: you need your own public method to do the work, you dont call the onClick on the fragment. it makes no sense

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Answer (score 2):

You're not wrong for wanting to keep your `Activity` code simple and readable. But the `Fragment` approach is weird. Background fragments have their place but this is not one of them. I think all you need to do is make a new `class` for each log in function. You can then call that class when the right button is pressed and outsource the actual loggin in that way. The basic set up would be something like this

```
googleAuthButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        GoogleLogIn logIn = new GoogleLogIn(new LoggedInListener(){

            @Override
            public void loggedIn(String whatever){
                      //if you need info from the log in use it here
            }

        });
        logIn.logMeIn(value);
    }
});
```

Then in your GoogleLogInClass

```
    public class GoogleLogIn{

        private LoggedInListener listener;       

        public GoogleLogIn(LoggedInListener listener){
            this.listener = listener; 
        }

        public void logMeIn(String info){
           //whatever you need to do to log in
           if(someConditionTrue){
               listener.loggedIn(someValueReturned);
           } else {
               listener.loggedIn(someValueThatIsFalse);
           }
        }
    }
```

My general idea is just to move the logic into a class which you call onClick of the button. You can then call some method to do whatever you want. You get feedback from the log in class using a callback which will return whaver you need to the host activity so you can use it later.

I don't know what's required to log into google+ or facebook so for now this is the best I can do. If all you need to do is pass some data and return a response, you can simplify things further by just making you log in class extend `AsyncTask` and implement the log in that way. Just pass your values in as params when you call execute().

**Edit - call method from XML**
If the above code looks too crazy because of the nested callabcks you can make this even simpler. In the XML where you declare the button, you can add an `onClick` option. This allows you to specify a public method in the activity that is called when the button is pressed. No call back. No nonsense. If you followed this approach you would just add the following

```
public void nameThisMethodWhateverYouWant(View v){
    /call your log in class here
}
```

This is even easier to read. I feel like the XML onclick function was only added after a certain API level but with the support package I have personally run this as low as 2.3.6 without any issue.

Comment: My problem is that the [Facebook sign-in sample](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/) code is designed as a Fragment and the [Google+ sign-in sample](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) is designed as an Activity. As such, they override a bunch of parent methods, so my problem was that I didn't know how to translate these models to a generic class (for instance, how to set up everything contained in both of their onCreate() methods in a generic way).

Comment: @Archer2486 what you really need to do is read the link I gave you in my comment about how to communicate with an activity, that is your real problem. that way everything is in a fragment like it should be and you activity handles it like it should

Comment: @tyczj The link you'd posted does seem helpful. Reading through it right now. Thanks.

Comment: @Archer2486 you need your fragment to communicate with your activity and that is specifically what i linked to you

Comment: If you have to use a fragment you can just use an interface that will allow you to access the activity from the fragment. You can then call back to the activity when whatever you want is done.